# In AppleScript, I am trying to get an piece of information from a website and have it pop up in a dialog box

Tags: applescript

More specifically this information: http://colejohnsoncreative.com/personal/ai/currentdegree.php

I want to pull that number (current temperature in my city) and have it displayed in a dialog box, or have my computer say it. I want to have something like this:
**say** "it's *currentDegree*"

and the current temperature will be said.

I have been told to use *curl* but I cant seem to find too much information on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `curl` Unix command to download your web page like this:

```
property theURL : "http://colejohnsoncreative.com/personal/ai/currentdegree.php"

set theValue to do shell script "curl " & theURL
display dialog theValue buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
```